# vue does not display in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display a follow button which in vue file but i have failed to yet i have ran npm run watch and did not succeed then tried to clear cache and run npm install but all in vain, any help
here is my vue file called FollowButton.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">follow btn</button>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },
    
}
</script>
```

here is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('follow-button', require('./components/FollowButton.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
});
```

my index file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="hi" style="height: 100px; 
width:100px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 mt-5">
        <div class="first d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
            <div>{{ $user ->username}}
                <follow-button></follow-button>
            </div>
        @can('update', $user->profile)
            <div><a href="/post/create" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="margin-
```

left:15px;">Add Post

```
        @endcan
        </div>
       
        @can('update', $user->profile)
            <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-success" >Edit Profile</a>
        @endcan
        <div class="second d-flex mt-3">
            <div style="margin:0 15px 0 0;"><strong>{{$user ->posts->count()}} 
</strong>posts</div>
            <div style="margin:0 15px 0 0;"><strong>13.3k</strong>followers</div>
            <div style="margin:0 15px 0 0;"><strong>43k</strong>following</div>
        </div>
        <div class="third mt-3">
            <div>{{$user->profile->title}}</div>
            <div>{{$user->profile->description}}</div>
            <div><a href="{{$user->profile->url}}" target="_blank">{{$user->profile->url}}</a> 
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    @foreach($user -> posts as $post)
    <div class="col-lg-4 pb-4" style="height: 55vh;">
        <a href="/post/{{$post->id}}">
        <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image}} "  alt="hello world" class="img-fluid w-100 h- 
100">
        </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach;
    
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Does `npm run watch` compile without any errors? Are you getting any errors in dev tools > console?

Comment: it does not through any error

Comment: If npm compiles without any error and you have included the `app.js` file in your `layouts.app` then vue should be detected in the dev tools. If you have installed vue dev-tools are you getting `vue` tab in your browser dev tools (normally comes up with F12)

Comment: actually i have this error in console Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function

Comment: Are you using Vue 3? Vue 3 doesn't have `component` method I guess

Comment: am using vue 3.2

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3 the way to create a new app is

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import FollowButton from './components/FollowButton.vue';

let app = createApp({});

//To load global components

app.component('follow-button', FollowButton);

//Mount the app to the element identified via selector
app.mount('#app');
```